# How to Structure Normalized Redux Store When Loading Data

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to create a React/Redux app which lists books. Each book then has related books. I know I should structure my redux store in some sort of normalized fashion like so:

```
{
  books: {
    'book1id': {
      title: 'Book 1',
      author: 'Author 1',
      relatedBooks: ['book2id', 'book3id']
    },
    'book2id': {
      title: 'Book 2',
      author: 'Author 2',
      relatedBooks: ['book1id']
    }
  }
}
```

and load each book as necessary.

The issue is where to store loading/error data from the API requests? Some ideas I had were to create an object for every book such as

```
books: {
  'book1id': {
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
    book: {
      title: 'Book 1',
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

But that seems to detract slightly from the readability/intuitiveness of the state. Is there a better way to structure the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I structure my redux store so that it includes an entities object for all of my relational data and I store things specific to a page or a set of routes in separate parts of the state. My state tree might look something like this:

```
const state = {
  entities: {
    books: {
      ...
    },
    authors: {
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  booksPage: {
    isLoading: false
  }
}
```

Now I am keeping track of my relational state separate from the state of my UI components. I would not recommend trying to store a `isLoading` state in an individual entity since that entity may or may not exist. If you need more granular loading/error state on a per entity basis then rather on a set of entities you have a few options. The first option is keep a set of IDs that are currently loading. This is not a very practical solution because you can't track success or failure with an ID simply being in a set or not.

The next, better solution is to keep a map from ID to a status object that includes if an individual entity is loading, if it was successful or if it failed to load and what the errors were.

```
const state = {
  entities: {
    books: {
      ...
    },
    authors: {
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  booksPage: {
    loading: {
      book1: {
        status: 'FAILED',
        error: 'Network request failed.'
      },
      book2: {
        status: 'SUCCESS',
      },
      book3: {,
        status: 'IN_PROGRESS'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In summary, I find separating out your relational state into an entities child object while having page specific sections of state to be working quite well for me.

Comment: I was planning on having the application stack multiple of these books on top of one another (a StackNavigator) for react native. As a result I don't think I can have one global isLoading since of the user tries to load one book and then goes to another while the first is still loading?

Comment: As I had mentioned in my answer, if you do need that sort of granularity you can do a few things, such as keeping a set of IDs that are in the loading state in a separate part of your state tree. Although, a better solution, is to keep a map from ID to status object which could include if it is loading, if there are any errors, and so on. Again, I would separate out relational state and put that UI state in a separate part of your tree. Hopefully this provides a more clear answer!

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, I am glad I could help. I will edit the answer to reflect some of this discussion.

Comment: What if a user visits /book/1, but the entities are loaded when the user visits /users, is there a solution to making sure the correct data is loaded when a user visits a single page?

Comment: @Notflip You have a couple of options. You can check your store for a book with the ID of "1", it could be possible your user has already requested it. If it is not present in your store you can request it and then cache it in your store. Alternatively, I might recommend taking a look at the work being done with [suspense](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCQgE4mTnjU) because it has implications on how data fetching is done which may change your mind about how you go about implementing the above described case.